# django get queryset which is latest of other column value

Tags: python, django

I have a model with some columns, between them there are 2 columns: equipment_id (a CharField) and date_saved (a DateTimeField).
I have multiple rows with the same equipment_id and but different date_saved (each time the user saves the record I save the now date time).
I want to retrieve a list of records that have a specific equipment_id and is the latest saved, i.e.:
| Equipment_id | Date_saved |

| --- ----- | --------------------- -------- |

| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:10:23|
| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:11:52|
| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:22:03|
| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:31:15|
| 1062a   | 21-DEC-2020 10:11:52|
| 1062a   | 25-DEC-2020 10:22:03|
| 1073a   | 20-DEC-2020 10:31:15|

Output:
| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:31:15|
| 1062a   | 25-DEC-2020 10:22:03|
| 1073a   | 20-DEC-2020 10:31:15|

I have tried various approach without success:

```
try:  
    progall=Program.objects.filter(equipment_id__startswith=str(b_id_to_search)).latest('saved_date')
```

The command doesn't work, the program goes to the except line

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can pass arguments to [`queryset.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) that specify the field(s) to return distinct values for in your query. You need to use `order_by` correctly here, you should order by the field your are passing to  `distinct` and then order by the second field so that the records that you want are first (`'-saved_date'` here so you get the latest for each `equipment_id`)

```
progall = Program.objects.filter(
    equipment_id__startswith=str(b_id_to_search)
).order_by=(
    'equipment_id',
    '-saved_date'
).distinct(
    'equipment_id'
)
```

Comment: I use mysql. Same result,the try: fails, it goes to the except:

Answer (score 0):

```
Program.objects.filter(equipment_id__startswith=b_id_to_search).latest("saved_date")
```

This should do.

Comment: What exception did you catch?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know, because I tried several approach and nothing worked. Now I am using a raw sql query. Amongst the exceptions I had: An exception of type TypeError occurred. Arguments:
("'Program' object is not iterable",)

Comment: or An exception of type AttributeError occurred. Arguments:
("'tuple' object has no attribute 'distinct'",)

Comment: I can't see the code of what you're trying now, so i can't do much but i think using raw sql is too far.